# Plotting with 2 variables and given list of f(u,v) values

Tags: plotting

Lets say I have a function y with 2 variables u and v :

$f(u,v)=y=u+4v$

I want to plot y in 2-D. My first axis is u and my second is v. How do I plot this, if I have a list of values for my y?

I tried

```
g[y_]:= InverseFunction[y[u_,v_]]
```

and put my values in with `g/@{1,2,3,4,5}`
and then created

```
Table[g[ylist[[i]]{i,1,Length[ylist]}]
```

This does not work.

Then I tried

```
aa = Table[ ]

plot = ContourPlot[u+4v, {u, -24, 24}, {v, -20, 20}, Contours -> aa]
```

but what do I put in `Table[  ]`? I only have the values for y.

Thank you for the answers. I solved my Problem by just adding my list of values with

`Contours->{1,2,3}`.

```
plot = ContourPlot[u+4v, {u, -24, 24}, {v, -20, 20}, Contours -> {1,2,3}]
```

Comment: I don't think the problem you have is finding a representation of your wishes in Mathematica. What you seem to want is expressed so fuzzily that most probably you didn't really think about the problem itself.  I suggest you try to come up with a better description of your problem. One thing to note is that your function is not invertible. For any given y there's an infinite amount of u and v values that yield this y value.  So that's one reason (apart from incorrect syntax) your InverseFunction doesn't work. In the last code box you could put the values  in a list and use e.g. `aa={3,7,9}`.

Comment: Is `ContourPlot` what you want?  (The inverse function does not exist mathematically, since `y` is not one-to-one, so that cannot be what you're after.)  Why not just go through some of the docs for `ContourPlot` and substitute your `u+4v, {u, -24, 24}, {v, -20, 20}` for the functions there?  If you start with `ContourPlot[u+4v, {u, -24, 24}, {v, -20, 20}]`, you can put your mouse over a contour line and it will tell you the value of the contour (that could go in your `aa` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Using the default contours in `ContourPlot` you will see that your function ranges from about `-100` to `100` within your `PlotRange`.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[u + 4 v, {u, -24, 24}, {v, -20, 20}, 
  ContourLabels -> True, 
  Contours -> Range[-100, 100, delta]], {{delta, 25}, {5, 10, 20, 25, 
   40, 50}}, ControlType -> SetterBar]
```

[image]